# short summary about video files (resolution, size, duration, codec)

Tags: command-line, video, multimedia, media

I use [mediainfo](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/mediainfo) at the moment.

It's too detailed

```
$ mediainfo vine.mp4 | wc -l
  66
```

I wish a command with only short summary. 6 lines of output.

Comment: What information should these 6 lines contain?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First define a shell function:

```
shortinfo() { 
   mediainfo --Inform="General;Duration=%Duration/String3%\nFile size=%FileSize/String1%" "$@"
   mediainfo --Inform="Video;Resolution=%Width%x%Height%\nCodec=%CodecID%" "$@"; 
}
```

Now, use this shell function on your video file.  For example:

```
$ shortinfo sample.mp4
Duration=00:00:10.027
File size=13 MiB
Resolution=1920x1080
Codec=avc1
```

To make the shell function permanent, place it in your `~/.bashrc` file.

#### How it works

`mediainfo` allows for custom output but, as far as I can tell, the custom output can only come from one section (general, video, audio) at a time.  This leads us to need two `mediainfo` commands.  The first selects information from the `general` category:

```
mediainfo --Inform="General;Duration=%Duration/String3%\nFile size=%FileSize/String1%" "$@"
```

The second selects information from the `Video` category:

```
mediainfo --Inform="Video;Resolution=%Width%x%Height%\nCodec=%CodecID%" "$@";
```

As you can see, the output allows us to insert any text we like and then substitute in file parameters using a string surrounded by percent signs, such as `%CodecID%`.  Information can be put on one line or spread out over several.  To insert a line break, use the string `\n`.

For a list of all the possible file parameters that you can put in your custom output, run:

```
mediainfo --info-parameters | less
```

Answer (score 5):

Also now possible on the command line:

```
mediainfo --Output=$'General;File=%FileName%\\nDuration=%Duration/String3%\\nFile size=%FileSize/String1% \nVideo;Resolution=%Width%x%Height%\\nCodec=%CodecID%\\n\\n' *.mkv
```

Note the "\n" between the sections

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04

MediaInfo Command line, 
MediaInfoLib - v17.12